# Is there a way to open a 64-bit exe from a thread using 32-bit python 2.7 on windows?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess, 32bit-64bit

I have a tkinter UI I am building in 32-bit python 2.7, and I've made a button which I would ultimately like to open an outside application (64-bit exe file) without interrupting the UI. My button starts a thread, which in turn starts a subprocess with a new console window and calls the full path of my exe file. If I type this full path into a cmd window outside the python script, my application opens successfully.

I get the error: WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I understand this requires either running a 64-bit version of python, or a 32-bit version of my application. However, is there an alternative solution that can be solved with code rather than altering my version of python or the application? For simplicity I've included some example code below.

Thanks for the help!!

```
self.VMD_button = tk.Button(self, text="Launch VMD", command=self.show_VMD)

def show_VMD(self):
     VMD_cmd = '"%s"' % "C:\VMD.exe"
     thread= Thread(target=self.call_subprocess, args=[VMD_cmd])
     thread.daemon = True
     thread.start()

def call_subprocess(self, cmd):
     proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE).wait()
```

Comment: You can't run 64bit Applications on 32bit Windows. The error indicates you are running a 32bit Windows: `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`, this has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the answer is "no."  And, what happens is what you just got.  Your application is 32-bit and therefore it only knows about 32-bit applications.  It might be incapable of launching a 64-bit process.  The opposite case *would* work because there is *backward* (but, not forward) compatibility.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I may have to just setup a 64-bit version of python after all.